# twitter model associations in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, twitter, model

I am trying to build a twitter like data model in rails. This is what I have come up with.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :microposts, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :mentions
  has_many :hashtags
end

class Mention< ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :micropost
end

class Hashtag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :micropost
end
```

Should I be using a has_many through association somewhere or is this accurate?

Edit: The final twitter MVC model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :microposts, :dependent => :destroy

  userID
end

class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :link2mentions, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :mentions, through: :link2mentions

  has_many :link2hashtags, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :hashtags, through: :link2hashtags

  UserID
  micropostID
  content
end

class Link2mention < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :micropost
    belongs_to :mention

    linkID
    micropostID
    mentionID
end

class Mention < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :link2mentions, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :microposts, through: :link2mentions

  mentionID
  userID
end
```

Edit 2: A concise and accurate explanation

http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging?view=asciicast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If two microposts use the same hashtag, you probably don't want to create two database records for that hashtag. In this case you would use `has_many through`:

```
class Hashtagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :micropost
  belongs_to :hashtag
end

class Hashtag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hashtaggings
  has_many :microposts, through: :hashtaggings
end

class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :hashtaggings
  has_many :hashtags, through: :hashtaggings
end
```

When you create the `Hashtagging` migration, make sure it has the `micropost_id` and `hashtag_id` columns.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Two microposts could also have the same mention(s). Would I have to use the has_many through model here?

Comment: What is the purpose of the hashtagging table. If it is to store links to the hashtags table why would each micropost have multiple hashtaggings?

Comment: hashtaggings is a [join model](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association). It holds the association between the two other models. In the database you might have some microposts with ids 1,2 and some hashtags with ids 1,2,3,4 then the hashtaggings will be something like `(micropost_id: 1, hastag_id: 3)`, `(micropost_id: 2, hastag_id: 4)` and so on.

Comment: I believe this is a similar solution to what you are explaining. Where the link table is the hashtagging table. Thanks!

http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_qQDfjePruAM/SwMtLR97BzI/AAAAAAAAElo/5v7UX2cXA_o/s1600/TwitterERDiag.jpg